# Python: webbrowser.open("") opens a file explorer window

Tags: python, windows-8, python-3.2, python-webbrowser

I'm coding a very simple url opener that gets the url in the terminal window (using `input`) and opens it with `webbrowser.open`.

The problem is that when nothing is put into the input (it's run `webbrowser.open("")`), a file explorer window appears instead of my web browser, and when I put something in the input, for example, http://www.google.com (it's run `webbrowser.open("http://www.google.com")`) it correctly opens google chrome. What's happening?

I'm running python 3.2.2 on windows 8, AMD. Thanks in any advance.

Comment: at a guess it interprets "" as a filepath and thinks you want to open fileexplorer ... what would you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, on the Python webpage for the [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) module, under [`webbrowser.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open), it says

> Note that on some platforms, trying to open a filename using this function, may work and start the operating system’s associated program.

Your computer realizes that you aren't trying to open a URL, so it attempts to open a file instead and because there is no input, it just opens your file explorer.